# Embed FLV with only audio playing?

Tags: php, html, video-streaming, audio-streaming

Is it possible to embed an FLV (video) in a web page but only play the audio with no video at all?

Sort of like running `mplayer -vo null myfile.flv` (starting a media player with `null` as video output), only for a web page with a PHP backend.

I would *love* to see a solution, especially if it does not use Flash.

Thanks!

Edit: server side conversion is not an option since the script runs on a shared hosting where CPU intensive tasks are not welcome.

Comment: Why not just take the audio out of the video file, and upload it separately?

Comment: The process needs to be automatic and server side conversion is not an option since the script runs on a shared hosting where CPU intensive tasks are not welcome.

Comment: You want to play Flash video without Flash without converting your video?  How do you expect to do that?  You know you can get a VPS for $5/mo. to convert for you.  That's probably cheaper than your shared hosting.  And sure, you can play video on a page with audio only... one easy way is to set its size to `0`.  What a waste of bandwidth though.